# Windows 8 freezes all the time

Tags: freeze, windows-8-preview, bsod

I'm running Windows 8 Release Preview on the following system:

- AMD FX-8150
- 16 GB 1800 RAM
- ATI HD5850

I experience BSOD's and freezes of the whole system all the time with random frequencies. Sometimes the systems runs for 10 hours, I'm playing games and everything works fine. Than I just browse around and the system freezes. Can't move my mouse anymore, Numlock-Key doesn't work anymore and so does Ctrl+Alt+Delete.

I checked what happened during the freeze and found this:

> ATI EEU Client event error
>   Error ID: 16388
>   Provider [Name] ATIeRecord

I tried to google the solution and found that installing Hyper-V should fix the problem. It didn't I also tried different drivers for my graphics card (both the 12.7 beta  and the current Windows 8 beta drivers) but the freezes come back.

Today I tried creating a movie with Windows Movie Maker (yeah, I really did) and it always crashes after the saving of the movie has gone on for about 15 - 30 minutes. (Saving the whole movie should take about an hour, but I never get that far). Maybe this is a helpful hint.

This is what I tried so far:

- Installing latest drivers
- Installing Hyper-V

And please no comments like *Duh, use Linux...* or *OMG it's a BETA!!!*
I'm looking for advice, maybe someone could already fix this issue even though we're talking about a beta - or more like a release candidate here.

Comment: How up to date are your video drivers?

Comment: I tried the latest Windows 7 and the latest Windows 8 video drivers.